# What will be the ideal method to convert the milliseconds to minutes in Kotlin

Tags: datetime, kotlin, calendar

In **Kotlin**, what will be the appropriate way of converting milliseconds (in `Long` type) to minutes?

Comment: Just divide the number?

Comment: When? Nowadays `TimeUnit` is probably a solid approach. In 5 years maybe there will be better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `TimeUnit` class which can convert different time units:

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds)
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Kotlin 1.6, you can use `kotlin.time.Duration` type to perform duration unit conversions:

```
longMillis.toDuration(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS).inWholeMinutes
```

or using the extension property `Long.milliseconds`:

```
longMillis.milliseconds.inWholeMinutes
```